# How do you change an angular property inside a html event handler without using a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm working on Angular 2 based application. I want to know whether we can set a angular variable inside a HTML Event Handler, is there any possible way?
The example given below ( identifying loading of image and showing a spinner ) is to give an idea about the problem.

```
<img [class.hidden]="!loaded" src="{{imageUrl}}" 
    onload="{{loaded}}=true;" />

<img *ngIf="!loaded" src="loader.gif" />
```

Error Code:

```
browser_adapter.js:77 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'onload' since it isn't a known native property ([class.hidden]="!loaded" src="{{imageUrl}}" 
 [ERROR ->]onload="{{loaded}}=true;" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img [class.hidden]="!loaded" src="{{imageUrl}}" 
    (load)="loaded=true" />
```

`(eventName)="eventHandler"` is for subscribing to events in Angular2.
`onload` is the JavaScript event handler for the `load` event. For Angular2 you subscribe to the event by omitting the `on` and use just the plain event name.

**Hint**

You should be aware that if the expression results to `false` this causes `preventDefault` to be called on the event

```
<img [class.hidden]="!loaded" src="{{imageUrl}}" 
    (load)="loaded=false" />
```

To work around `;true` can be added so the entire expression result is `true`

```
<img [class.hidden]="!loaded" src="{{imageUrl}}" 
    (load)="loaded=false;true" />
```